# How to simplify Big O algebra with multiple variables

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

Assume that the worst-case runtime of an algorithm can be described as:

`T(n) = O(n) + O(r^2) + O(n-r)`

With `n` being the input size and `r` being the index at which a partition was created per the algorithm.

Can this equation be simplified further? If the variables were all `n` then it would be `O(n^2)` but can the same idea be applied when `r` is involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `O(n-r)` is suppressed by `O(n)` you can write `T(n) = O(n) + O(r^2)`. Also, as you know that `r` is between 0 and `n`, you can write `T(n) = O(n + r^2)`. However, the exact term is `T(n,r) = O(n + r^2)`.

Comment: What if the values were shifted slightly? For example `T(n) = O(logn) + O(n-r)`? I'm trying to grasp when we know for sure that something is suppressed.

Comment: @TravisM, In this case, you can say it is `O(n)`. However, the exact term is `O(n + log(n) - r)`, but definitely it is `O(n)`.